# Нестандартное обособление уточняющего обстоятельства в романе М. А. Булгакова

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, правила

**Булгаков М.А.:**

*На этот раз пришлось ждать недолго.  Звуки двери. Шажки. Шажки  стихли.
Отчаянный крик. Мяуканье кошки. Шажки быстрые, дробные, вниз, вниз, вниз!
Поплавский  дождался. Крестясь  и что-то  бормоча,  пролетел  печальный
человек,  без  шляпы,  с совершенно безумным лицом, исцарапанной лысиной и в
совершенно мокрых штанах. Он **начал рвать**  за ручку выходную  дверь, в страхе не соображая, куда она открывается — наружу или внутрь, — наконец **совладал с нею и вылетел** на солнце во двор.
Проверка  квартиры была  произведена...*

Как объяснить постановку второго **тире?** Возможно ли **другое** оформление?

Comment: "Наружу и внутрь" явно не относится никак к последней части, однако является продолжением происходящего действия. Наверное можно было поставить скобки, но это действие, так что активнее. Игра различных действий.

Comment: «Как объяснить постановку второго тире?» — Постановка первого тире вас, значит. не смущает?)) «Возможно ли другое оформление?» — И не одно!

Comment: Нет, не смущает)) Здесь я могу применить правило Розенталя п.10 Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается: 1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111  Правда, оно для приложений, но это "ничево"). Это общий принцип сочетания знаков, он даже в прямой речи применяется. Для расширения области применения можно использовать правило блоков Лопатина.  // Есть много вариантов решений?  Но я люблю, чтобы по правилам))

Comment: Можно и первое тире убрать (поставить запятую), но тогда грамматика будет неясно обозначена, вот ведь в чем дело.  Нет ли у вас правила для двух тире?)

Answer (score 2):

*Он начал рвать за ручку выходную дверь, в страхе не соображая, ***куда*** она открывается — ***наружу или внутрь***, — наконец совладал с нею и вылетел на солнце во двор.*

Конструкцию можно понимать не как уточнение, а как обобщающее слово (обобщающее обстоятельство ***куда***) при однородных членах (однородных обстоятельствах ***наружу или внутрь***); а раз это так и раз эти однородные члены стоят в середине сложного предложения, то можно выделить их с двух сторон тире, придав таким образом членам характер вставного  замечания. При этом второе тире сочетается с запятой, закрывающей придаточное изъяснительное предложение, распространяющее деепричастие *не соображая.*

Можно и не ставить второе тире и оформить так, с закрытием придаточного лишь запятой:

*Он начал рвать за ручку выходную дверь, в страхе не соображая, ***куда*** она открывается — ***наружу или внутрь***, наконец совладал с нею и вылетел на солнце во двор.*

Строго говоря, члены ***наружу или внутрь*** стоят не в середине своего предложения, именно придаточного, а в его конце, и поэтому вроде как и одной запятой было бы достаточно, запятой закрывающей придаточную часть.

Однако за придаточным идёт продолжение главного предложения, и второе тире именно что подчёркивает вставной характер этих обстоятельств, характер добавочного, попутного замечания, пусть они и стоят не в середине, а в конце своего предложения.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. (1) Могу я считать, что по семантике это уточнение/пояснение местоимения куда? Другими словами, открывается куда именно?  (2) На какое правило Розенталя или ПАС здесь нужно сослаться, если это потребуется?